# How to assign hotkey of pressing Alt key twice (Alt+Release+Alt) in Autohotkey?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

How to assign a hotkey of quickly pressing `{Alt}` **key twice** in Autohotkey?
In other words: How to assign `Press Alt`+`Release Alt`+`Press Alt` as a hotkey?
In other words: How to assign key down `{Alt}` key then key up `{Alt}` key then *quickly* key down `{Alt}`?.

I want to set the **time** between releasing `{Alt}` key then pressing it again (to be very small) in order to activate hotkey.
*• Example:* if the user pressed `{Alt}` key then released it then waited for 5 seconds then pressed `{Alt}` key again, the hotkey shouldn't be working or active at all. But if he pressed `{Alt}` key again before 1.5 seconds, then the hotkey will work. I want to be able to set this time.
*• Analogy:* it's something like double clicking a mouse button and setting the time between 1st and second click in order for the double-click action to be triggered. But what I'm looking for instead is setting a double click for a keyboard key.

Answer (score 1):

There is a script out on the Autohotkey forum that already accomplishes this: [RapidHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/35566-rapidhotkey/).

There are two functions listed on the page that must be included in your script, but they enable you to set the hotkey, number of clicks required, and the time allowed between clicks.  A sample of this could be

```
~Alt::RapidHotkey("myLabel", 2, 0.3, 1)

myLabel:
Msgbox Alt was double clicked
Return
```

Comment: It would be nice if you included the `RapidHotkey()` function in your answer, as the link you included may not work in the future.

Comment: this is awesome, i remapped double alt, to win+b (to show auto-hidden windows taskbar without showing start menu)

Answer (score 0):

If you want in Autohotkey, to do a AHK Action if a Hotkey is pressed Twice (or a Counts of clicks)

for example Click (ALt 2x) - do a Action.

you can use these two AHK Scipts. (The first Script is Large, but you are able to do Many thinks.)

1 - KeypressValueToREG.ahk - this will Put Any (Keyboard Click Movements) and (Mouse Click Movements) to only One (Windows Registry Key)

2 - ShowKeypressValue.ahk - This Will Show visualy the KeypressValue & it will run a Ahk code if Alt key is pressed Twice.

note : You need to run Both Scrips Together.

[image: windows registry get keypress value]

[image: get keypress value autohotkey]

KeypressValueToREG.ahk

```
;KeypressValueToREG.ahk comes from KeypressOSD.ahk that was Created by Author RaptorX
; Open this Script in Wordpad and For Changelog look to the Bottom of the script. 
;This code works with a getkeyname from a Dllcall (See Bottom Script- by Lexikos)
;you can press the esc key to exit.

#SingleInstance force
#NoEnv
SetBatchLines, -1
ListLines, Off

; Settings
    global TransN                := 200      ; 0~255
    global ShowSingleKey         := True
    global ShowMouseButton       := True
    global ShowSingleModifierKey := True
    global ShowModifierKeyCount  := true
    global ShowStickyModKeyCount := false
    global DisplayTime           := 2000     ; In milliseconds
    global GuiPosition           := "Bottom" ; Top or Bottom
    global FontSize              := 50
    global GuiHeight             := 115

CreateGUI()
CreateHotkey()
return

OnKeyPressed:
    try {
        key := GetKeyStr()
        ShowHotkey(key)
        SetTimer, HideGUI, % -1 * DisplayTime
    }
return

OnKeyUp:
return

_OnKeyUp:
    tickcount_start := A_TickCount
return


CreateGUI() {
    global

    Gui, +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +Owner +LastFound +E0x20
    Gui, Margin, 0, 0
    Gui, Color, Black
    Gui, Font, cWhite s%FontSize% bold, Arial
    Gui, Add, Text, vHotkeyText Center y20

    WinSet, Transparent, %TransN%
}

CreateHotkey() {
    Loop, 95
    {
        k := Chr(A_Index + 31)
        k := (k = " ") ? "Space" : k

        Hotkey, % "~*" k, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*" k " Up", _OnKeyUp
    }

    Loop, 24 ; F1-F24
    {
        Hotkey, % "~*F" A_Index, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*F" A_Index " Up", _OnKeyUp
    }

    Loop, 10 ; Numpad0 - Numpad9
    {
        Hotkey, % "~*Numpad" A_Index - 1, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*Numpad" A_Index - 1 " Up", _OnKeyUp
    }

    Otherkeys := "WheelDown|WheelUp|WheelLeft|WheelRight|XButton1|XButton2|Browser_Forward|Browser_Back|Browser_Refresh|Browser_Stop|Browser_Search|Browser_Favorites|Browser_Home|Volume_Mute|Volume_Down|Volume_Up|Media_Next|Media_Prev|Media_Stop|Media_Play_Pause|Launch_Mail|Launch_Media|Launch_App1|Launch_App2|Help|Sleep|PrintScreen|CtrlBreak|Break|AppsKey|NumpadDot|NumpadDiv|NumpadMult|NumpadAdd|NumpadSub|NumpadEnter|Tab|Enter|Esc|BackSpace"
               . "|Del|Insert|Home|End|PgUp|PgDn|Up|Down|Left|Right|ScrollLock|CapsLock|NumLock|Pause|sc145|sc146|sc046|sc123"
    Loop, parse, Otherkeys, |
    {
        Hotkey, % "~*" A_LoopField, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*" A_LoopField " Up", _OnKeyUp
    }

    If ShowMouseButton {
        Loop, Parse, % "LButton|MButton|RButton", |
            Hotkey, % "~*" A_LoopField, OnKeyPressed
    }

    for i, mod in ["Ctrl", "Shift", "Alt"] {
        Hotkey, % "~*" mod, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*" mod " Up", OnKeyUp
    }
    for i, mod in ["LWin", "RWin"]
        Hotkey, % "~*" mod, OnKeyPressed
}

ShowHotkey(HotkeyStr) {
    WinGetPos, ActWin_X, ActWin_Y, ActWin_W, ActWin_H, A
    if !ActWin_W
        throw

    text_w := (ActWin_W > A_ScreenWidth) ? A_ScreenWidth : ActWin_W

    ;remove this gui codeline if you want only to Write the Value to Windows registry
    ;GuiControl,     , HotkeyText, %HotkeyStr%
    ;GuiControl,     , HotkeyText, %HotkeyStr%

    RegWrite, REG_SZ, HKEY_CURRENT_USER,software\GetKeypressValue,KeypressValue,%HotkeyStr%

    ;remove this gui codeline if you want only to Write the Value to Windows registry
    ;GuiControl, Move, HotkeyText, w%text_w% Center
    ;GuiControl, Move, HotkeyText, w%text_w% Center

    if (GuiPosition = "Top")
        gui_y := ActWin_Y
    else
        gui_y := (ActWin_Y+ActWin_H) - 115 - 50

    ;remove this gui codeline if you want only to Write the Value to Windows registry
    ;Gui, Show, NoActivate x%ActWin_X% y%gui_y% h%GuiHeight% w%text_w%
    ;Gui, Show, NoActivate x%ActWin_X% y%gui_y% h%GuiHeight% w%text_w%
}

GetKeyStr() {
    static modifiers := ["Ctrl", "Shift", "Alt", "LWin", "RWin"]
    static repeatCount := 1

    for i, mod in modifiers {
        if GetKeyState(mod)
            prefix .= mod " + "
    }

    if (!prefix && !ShowSingleKey)
        throw

    key := SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 3)

    if (key ~= "i)^(Ctrl|Shift|Alt|LWin|RWin)$") {
        if !ShowSingleModifierKey {
            throw
        }
        key := ""
        prefix := RTrim(prefix, "+ ")

        if ShowModifierKeyCount {
            if !InStr(prefix, "+") && IsDoubleClickEx() {
                if (A_ThisHotKey != A_PriorHotKey) || ShowStickyModKeyCount {
                    if (++repeatCount > 1) {
                        prefix .= " ( * " repeatCount " )"
                    }
                } else {
                    repeatCount := 0
                }
            } else {
                repeatCount := 1
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ( StrLen(key) = 1 ) {
            key := GetKeyChar(key, "A")
        } else if ( SubStr(key, 1, 2) = "sc" ) {
            key := SpecialSC(key)
        } else if (key = "LButton") && IsDoubleClick() {
            key := "Double-Click"
        }
        _key := (key = "Double-Click") ? "LButton" : key

        static pre_prefix, pre_key, keyCount := 1
        global tickcount_start
        if (prefix && pre_prefix) && (A_TickCount-tickcount_start < 300) {
            if (prefix != pre_prefix) {
                result := pre_prefix pre_key ", " prefix key
            } else {
                keyCount := (key=pre_key) ? (keyCount+1) : 1
                key := (keyCount>2) ? (key " (" keyCount ")") : (pre_key ", " key)
            }
        } else {
            keyCount := 1
        }

        pre_prefix := prefix
        pre_key := _key

        repeatCount := 1
    }
    return result ? result : prefix . key
}

SpecialSC(sc) {
    static k := {sc046: "ScrollLock", sc145: "NumLock", sc146: "Pause", sc123: "Genius LuxeMate Scroll"}
    return k[sc]
}

; by Lexikos - https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/110808-getkeyname-for-other-languages/#entry682236
GetKeyChar(Key, WinTitle:=0) {
    thread := WinTitle=0 ? 0
        : DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "ptr", WinExist(WinTitle), "ptr", 0)
    hkl := DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "uint", thread, "ptr")
    vk := GetKeyVK(Key), sc := GetKeySC(Key)
    VarSetCapacity(state, 256, 0)
    VarSetCapacity(char, 4, 0)
    n := DllCall("ToUnicodeEx", "uint", vk, "uint", sc
        , "ptr", &state, "ptr", &char, "int", 2, "uint", 0, "ptr", hkl)
    return StrGet(&char, n, "utf-16")
}

IsDoubleClick(MSec = 300) {
    Return (A_ThisHotKey = A_PriorHotKey) && (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < MSec)
}

IsDoubleClickEx(MSec = 300) {
    preHotkey := RegExReplace(A_PriorHotkey, "i) Up$")
    Return (A_ThisHotKey = preHotkey) && (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < MSec)
}

HideGUI() {
    Gui, Hide
}

~esc::exitapp    
;---------------------------------------------
; ChangeLog : v2.22 (2017-02-25) - Now pressing the same combination keys continuously more than 2 times,
;                                  for example press Ctrl+V 3 times, will displayed as "Ctrl + v (3)"
;             v2.21 (2017-02-24) - Fixed LWin/RWin not poping up start menu
;             v2.20 (2017-02-24) - Added displaying continuous-pressed combination keys.
;                                  e.g.: With CTRL key held down, pressing K and U continuously will shown as "Ctrl + k, u"
;             v2.10 (2017-01-22) - Added ShowStickyModKeyCount option
;             v2.09 (2017-01-22) - Added ShowModifierKeyCount option
;             v2.08 (2017-01-19) - Fixed a bug
;             v2.07 (2017-01-19) - Added ShowSingleModifierKey option (default is True)
;             v2.06 (2016-11-23) - Added more keys. Thanks to SashaChernykh.
;             v2.05 (2016-10-01) - Fixed not detecting "Ctrl + ScrollLock/NumLock/Pause". Thanks to lexikos.
;             v2.04 (2016-10-01) - Added NumpadDot and AppsKey
;             v2.03 (2016-09-17) - Added displaying "Double-Click" of the left mouse button.
;             v2.02 (2016-09-16) - Added displaying mouse button, and 3 settings (ShowMouseButton, FontSize, GuiHeight)
;             v2.01 (2016-09-11) - Display non english keyboard layout characters when combine with modifer keys.
;             v2.00 (2016-09-01) - Removed the "Fade out" effect because of its buggy.
;                                - Added support for non english keyboard layout.
;                                - Added GuiPosition setting.
;             v1.00 (2013-10-11) - First release.
;--------------------------------------------
```

ShowKeypressValue.ahk

```
#SingleInstance force
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop -MaximizeBox ; -Caption +Resize -MinimizeBox +Disabled -SysMenu -Owner +OwnDialogs
Gui, Add, Text, center y10 h50 w300 vVar,  %KeypressValue%
Gui, Color, White
Gui, show
size=20
Gui, Font, s%size%
GuiControl, Font, var

;run KeypressValueToREG.ahk - together with ShowKeypressValue.ahk
;The Features Are:
; - It will Show On your Screen, [All your Mouse Movements] and [All Keyboard Shortcuts Movement]
; - You can Make Scripts, that can do actions with MultiClicks on All Keyboard Shortcuts Clicks, How Nice Is that. 

loop
{
RegRead, KeypressValue, HKEY_CURRENT_USER,software\GetKeypressValue,KeypressValue ; read KeypressValue
sleep 50
GuiControl,, var, %KeypressValue%



if (KeypressValue="Alt ( * 2 )") ;use this for [1x=Alt][2x=Alt ( * 2 )][3x=Alt ( * 3 )] [and many more]
{
;Here you can put any AHK CODE 
msgbox you did click Alt 2x Times
}

if (KeypressValue="Alt ( * 3 )") ;use this for [1x=Alt][2x=Alt ( * 2 )][3x=Alt ( * 3 )] [and many more]
{
;Here you can put any AHK CODE 
msgbox you did click Alt 3x Times
}


} ;End Loop


~esc::exitapp
```

And If you want to use it with exact MilliSeconds Control Values.

you can then **only!** Use This Example:

example2.ahk

Note:In Line (SetTimer, CountClicks, 100) you can Optimize (change) the number 100. (so that it works fine on your system.) (Any Ahk Scripts that runs in the background does have a Default=250ms)

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force
;#NoTrayIcon

a1 := -1
b1 := 0

esc::exitapp ;click (esc) key to stop the script. 

;~ key the default function Alt is also active. 
;and if you Click the Alt Button 3x times, it will Execute Ahk Code Part 3
~Alt::
if(a1 = -1)
{
a1 := 4
#Persistent
SetTimer, CountClicks, 100
}
else
{
a1 := 3
}
return

CountClicks:
if(a1 = 3)
{
b1 := b1 + 1
}
if(a1 = 0)
{
msgbox you did Click <Alt> Key > %b1%x times
if (b1=1) 
{
;if Click 1x - Then Execute Ahk Code Part 1 
;Here you can put any code for Part 1 
msgbox Executed Ahk Code Part 1      
} 
if (b1=2) 
{
;if Click 2x - Then Execute Ahk Code Part 2  
;Here you can put any code for Part 2 
msgbox Executed Ahk Code Part 2       
} 
if (b1=3) 
{
;if Click 3x - Then Execute Ahk Code Part 3 
;Here you can put any code for Part 3
msgbox Executed Ahk Code Part 3       
} 
if (b1=4) 
{
;if Click 4x - Then Execute Ahk Code Part 4 
;Here you can put any code for Part 4
msgbox Executed Ahk Code Part 4         
} 
b1 := 0
SetTimer, CountClicks , off
reload ; restart script
}
a1 := a1 - 1
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple script:

```
LAlt::
    If (A_PriorHotKey = "LAlt") AND (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 200){
        Send, {LAlt Down}
        KeyWait, LAlt
        Send, {LAlt Up}
    }
return
```

The if statement will check if the `LAlt` hotkey has been used in the last `200` milliseconds, if so, it will hold `LAlt` key down, and when `LAlt` physically goes up (you release the key), it will reflect the same in the OS.
Otherwise, it will do nothing, for example if the sequence was `LAlt`, some other key then `LAlt` again, it won't active, or if the time between pressings of `LAlt` was not quick enough (more than `200`ms) it will also not active.

Comment: This doesn't really work: the `ALT` key is taken by this function, and for example ALT+TAB doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This works to detect two fast <kbd>ALT</kbd> presses:

```
~LAlt::
    If (A_PriorHotKey = "~LAlt") AND (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 200){
        SoundBeep, 750, 500
    }
return
```

It is based on [Shayan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952524/how-to-assign-hotkey-of-pressing-alt-key-twice-altreleasealt-in-autohotkey/57448356#57448356) but I added `~` to make it work. Without it, ALT+TAB and other ALT+xxx don't work.