# Keyboard Macro Buttons Remap

Tags: autohotkey

I am not sure if the title is correct, let me explain my issue here...

I have a keyboard that has 5 macro keys (you have to assign them with a keystroke within the keyboard's software to be recognisable).

So what i want to do is to have those keys, lets say the first one "M1" so that if i press it i can launch some autohotkey scripts. Here comes the problem, as i mentioned previously, in order for the key to be recognisable, i have to assign it a key. The thing is that i do not want to assign any F1 F2... keys because i dont want autohotkey to trigger when i press the F1 F2... keys. So the solution i thought is to set M1 to Ctrl F1. This will solve the problem but it will not allow autohotkey to distinguise the difference between Ctrl M1 and just M1. That is because M1 is equal to Ctrl F1 and Ctrl M1 is also equal to Ctrl F1.

So how can i assign the macro keys to something that will not limit me using the modifier keys with the macro keys so i can get as many macro combinations as possible?

Something i tried is to set M1 to F13 (which is not on the keyboard so it will not limit me in any way) but the keyboard's software does not accept F13 and higher...

I did my best to explain, sorry if it doesnt make much sense.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

(My keyboard is the Creative k08)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work! So here is what i did...(This may only work for my keyboard's software).
So for every key of the keyboard, you can assign another key via the software just like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh24l.jpg
But the thing is that even though you see F13 in the text field (which i was able to send via autohotkey `o::send {F13}` , the software does not save this to the keyboard because this key does not exist. So if i close and open the software, the F13 I set, wont be there, and it will never work as F13.
So then I saw the "Recordings" section of the same menu, in which I am able to record many different keys with delays or even mouse clicks. So I recorded pressing "o" (which i have temporally mapped to send F13 and the software showed a key being pressed without a name, but i gave it a try and it does in fact work! So if I record F13 and I assign it to M1 key on my keyboard, when I press M1 it does send F13 and by this way I can use all the modifiers and still not sacrifice any key. 
Sorry for wasting your time by not having tested this recording feature earlier.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you can set the macro keys to be very complex hotkeys. I am unsure how the interaction is done with the macro keys and other keys pressed IE setting your <kbd>M1</kbd> to something like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M1</kbd>. You could try to do that and then have AHK have maps like:

```
!+F1::  ; maps to Alt + M1
!^+F1::  ; maps to Alt + Ctrl + M1
!+F2::  ; maps to Alt + Ctrl + M2
!^+F2::  ; maps to Alt + Ctrl + M2
```

Otherwise you might be limited to the macro buttons only triggering a single hotkey. In this case you can get a little tricky by adding a `KeyWait` for some key that you might want to modify it with. Something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> so that you could perform the usual script on pressing <kbd>M1</kbd>, which would timeout on the KeyWait when configured correctly, but if you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with it then you could trigger the KeyWait and thus perform a different action..

Comment: Thank you for your response. The main issue here is that if I map M1 to shift f1, then I cannot assign something to shift M1 because Shift M1 and just M1 will have the same exact recognition from ahk, as both are shift f1. Hope this makes sense. As for keywait, I did not really get how I could implement it, I will again have to assign M1 to something in order for ahk to recognise it.

Comment: So the issue I have is that I have currently set M1 as CTRL F1, and I want to launch the calculator for example when I press M1, and I want to launch for example Chrome when I press CTRL M1, which is not possible as I understand. Basically I want to use all the modifier keys, ctrl shift Windows and caps lock with the macro keys 

Comment: Yeah that is a bit tricky. What I was suggesting was that you could test if setting M1 to Ctrl + F1 and then physically pressing Shift + M1 would trigger a AHK hotkey of Shift + Ctrl + F1. This way you could at least get a few more modifiers out of it. Otherwise what I suggested on the KeyWait was more specifically using it to simulate a variable on your script.

Comment: From there you could do KeyWait, Shift, T1. This would wait 1 second for the Shift key to be released and if it was successful (check ErrorLevel) you could launch chrome, else launch calculator...It would only launch calculator after 1 second though...and KeyWait doesn't seem to have settings for ms waits.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I really appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar keyboard that had macro keys that had to be programmed before they could be used.  My solution to setting them up for executing AutoHotKey macros was to configure them to use highly unlikely key combinations, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> then capture those key sequences in AutoHotKey.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem with this is that if I set M1 to Ctrl shift f1,   then I will not be able to have autohotkey distinguish the difference between me pressing M1  or pressing Ctrl M1   or Shift M1.   Because M1 has all those modifiers on its own, I cannot use them afterwards. I cannot set M1 to launching the calculator and then set Ctrl M1 to launch Firefox because M1 is equal to Ctrl Shift F1, and Ctrl M1 is also equal to Ctrl Shift F1. I hope u got it  it's hard to explain

Comment: I see.  That does make it complicated.  Can you use the Creative software to set the M1 key to be a key that isn't on your keyboard?  Something like `£`, `¥`, or `€` ?  If so, you might be able to use AHK to map from that to your extra commands.

Comment: If you aren't able to resolve this to do things the way you currently envision, you might consider using multiple presses of either the M keys or the modifiers, similar to how I describe it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52955557/933524.  For example, press M1 one time for macro 1, two times for macro 2, etc. Or press Alt then M1 for macro 1, and Alt Alt M1 for macro 2, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. I did try to set the M1 to a symbol or even F13 or something but the software does not accept it. I will try your suggestions tomorrow and I will report back. Thanks